# Number of comparisons in Quicksort

Tags: quicksort

[image: Here is the question]

So would it be correct to say that the number of comparisons from level 1 to level 2 would be $2(n/2-1)$?

Or would it be more correct to say that the number of comparisons is $2^i(n/2^i-1)$?

Comment: From pevel 1 to level 2 is $n-1$

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the list entails comparing **every** element in the current list with the pivot. That is, if the list is of size $n$, you would have $n-1$ comparisons.

Then, the list is split into sizes $|B|$ and $|S|$ and continues recursively. On the $B$ part you will choose a pivot and make $|B|-1$ comparisons to split them into two (sub)lists. Same with $S$. This continues until you get list of size $1$, for which you computes $C(1)$.